# correlation measure in copula

Tags: correlation, copula

I'm reading about copula but I'm a bit confused about it: we know that the [Gaussian copula pdf](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copula_(probability_theory)#Gaussian_copula) is equal to :
$$C (u_1, u_2, u_3,…, u_n; Σ) = |Σ|^{-1/2} \exp (-1/2 ε^{T}(Σ^{-1} – I)ε)$$
where $Σ$ is the correlation matrix.

How that matrix calculated? can we calculate it by Kendall tau or Spearman or any other measure? what is the relationship between copula and those correlation measure?

Comment: This is the definition of a joint distribution, parameterised by $\Sigma$. Given a sample this matrix can be estimated by different methods, like maximum likelihood, Bayesian, &tc.